# Style precedence over binding

Tags: c#, wpf

In my example, no matter how I define styles for a behavior in my control, it gets only the style defined in the binding property. Ex.:

```
    <Style TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>                    
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    ....

    <Border Background="{Binding UserColor}">
```

When mouse is over control, the background does not turns yellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct behavior. Remove the direct assignment and add a setter to your style:

```
<Style TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding UserColor}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>                    
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Control.Background` property is a `DependencyProperty` and `DependencyProperty`s can be set from a variety of sources, eg. `Style Setter`, `Animation`, from code, etc. Because of this reason, Microsoft had to define an order of precedence to decide which of these possible ways to change the `DependencyProperty` value were more important than others.

It was logically decided that setting a `DependencyProperty` using inline XAML as you did in your example should 'override' values set from other sources, eg. from a `Style`. That is why the `Background` from your `Style` is not showing in your example. For full information of the `DependencyProperty` value precedence list, please see the [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

---

UPDATE >>>

Note that if you wanted to set a default `Background` colour for your `Border`, then you should declare it in the used `Style` and *not* inline, as we have already learned that that doesn't work:

```
<Style TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding UserColor}"/> <!-- Default -->
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>                    
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```